# Ubuntu upgrade 23.04 to 23.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, 23.04, 23.10

I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu but it's stuck on the "Setting new software channels" fetching file 116 of 149. I opened the main.log and it displayed that the cache can not be locked. "E: could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4425 (mantic). Then it shows a warning that removing the lock file might not be a solution and could harm the system. Problem is I am UPGRADING to MANTIC but MANTIC itself is holding the update??? How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have two package managers open? Or the same working in two different terminal windows? Or did your system get interrupted while a package manager was working?